# tracking ios installations with appsflyer

Tags: ios, iphone, appdelegate, appsflyer

I've integrated the appsflyer sdk successfully for tracking installations but encountered a synchronisation problem: the onConversionDataReceived method which I implemented in the AppDelegate is being called too late, what's the best practice to ensure it being called before i proceed with our app flow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onConversionDataReceived is called automatically from within the SDK, its not synchronization issue.

The conversion data needs to be calculated on Appsflyer's servers and sometimes it is dependent on external data (Facebook, twitter, etc..) this takes few seconds.

Another thing, once the conversion data is already calculated, onConversionDataReceived returns much faster.